# Trouble calling member function in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, watch

I'm trying to call a member function of a variable from within the watch window of VS 2010.  I keep getting the error, "member function not present".  I've searched google and SO and arrived at these attempts:

```
{,,Dll}var.member()
var.{,,Dll}member()
var.{,,Dll}namespace::class::member()
{,,Dll}member(&var)
{,,Dll}namespace::class::member(&var)
```

None work.  The errors are, respectedly:

```
"symbol 'var' not found"
"missing operand"
"missing operand"
"symbol 'var' not found"
"symbol 'var' not found"
```

However, `var` in the watch window works fine.

The function does exist.  I can call it from code.  I just can't seem to use it in a watch expression.  If I could I think I could answer my somewhat related question: [Viewing a pimpl from DLL in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843262/viewing-a-pimpl-from-dll-in-debugger)

Yes, symbols are loaded.  I can watch this:

```
{,,Dll}namespace::class::member
```

It results in a type I would expect.

Any ideas?

Edit: oh, and the var is of a type exported from 'Dll.dll' and imported by the current process I'm trying to debug (unit tests).

Comment: There is a bug in VS2010 that prevents the debugger from seeing local variables declared in a nested control structure - could it be what's causing your problem?

Comment: @riv Could be.  I don't suppose you have a link to a support case.

Comment: I think this is the right link: support.microsoft.com/kb/2452649