# "Function has no address" despite disabled optimization (/Od)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, msvc12

During debug in MSVC 2012, I am attempting to call some functions from the Watch window in order to dump data to files. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Function Matrix::Save has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.
```

The class `Matrix` is located in my own external library. A quick check showed that none of the methods in external libraries have addresses and all attempts to call them from Watch return this error, except for those which are defined in the header files. The methods in the main project all have addresses regardless of where they are defined.

Optimization is disabled throughout the solution, of course. Symbols are loaded normally. How do I fix it?

Comment: How is the library linked? Static? Dynamic? If dynamic, how loaded?

Comment: It's linked dynamically. What do you mean by "how loaded"?

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy you can have either implicit or explicit loading. If implicit, then the above may work fine. If explicit, then you need to call using the function pointers you've stored.

Comment: @IdeaHat The library is linked implicitly. Does this mean that it is loaded implicitly, too?

Comment: I don't think you can explicitly load it implicitly, IYSWIM, but it must be able to find the dll: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx "The operating system must be able to locate the DLL file when it loads the calling executable."

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I would expect to be able to call any function I liked in the watch window.

Comment: I checked the executable with depends.exe, the path points to the correct library in the output folder of the Debug configuration. Apart that I don't understand why calling some methods in Watch does work and calling other doesn't and that the error message is extremely misleading - are there any other approaches to doing anything advanced during debug except Watch? I would like to avoid hard-coding dumping methods, and the matrices in question are really huge, I cannot extract any meaningful information just by looking at their buffers.

Comment: Are you building the external lib from source as part of your solution or are you linking against a prebuilt binary? If it's the latter then you have no control over what compiler settings were used to build it

Comment: I am building it from source. Is there anything that I should check in the library project settings?

Comment: You could have a configurable hard-coded dump method. Previous watch windows have had problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844804/trouble-calling-member-function-in-debugger Also, has it loaded the symbols for your dll? If not tell it where they are: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx

Comment: Symbols are loaded, yes. As I posted below, static linking solves the problem. This in only an option as long as one builds the library from the code, of course, but this is my case. As for third-party libraries, your proposal with configurable hard-coded dump is probably the best. I'll wait for a couple of days and see if anyone comes with anything else.

Comment: Still no solution? I don't even understand why I'm getting this error in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I found a workaround in building the external library statically. With statically linked libraries, the addresses of methods are found. Configuration manager allows keeping dynamic libraries for the Release easily.

Comment: @javaLover I'm afraid I can't recall more details. It's been five years ago, I'm not working with C++ any more.

Answer (score 1):

As a simpler woraround, you can call target function(*Matrix::Save*) at least one time in current code branch. Then it will have an address because it is used.